# Search and display the table values while typing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I refer the following code from stack-overflow itself.but it will not working, anyone can tell what should I update this code.

```js
var $rows = $('#table tr');
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
    });
```

```css
body {padding: 20px;}
input {margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 2px 3px; width: 209px;}
td {padding: 4px; border: 1px #CCC solid; width: 100px;}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Search Event</title>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
    <link href="search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
   </head>
   <body>
     <center><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search"></center>
     <center><table id="table">
      <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Green</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Grapes</td>
       <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Orange</td>
       <td>Orange</td>
    </tr>
    </table></center>
   </body>
 </html>
```

with these simple concept am struggling so far.so please help me.

Comment: have you include jquery file ?

Comment: What is expected result ?

Comment: it working perfectly for me .https://jsfiddle.net/vq77u88y/

Comment: @ShailendraSharma After added jquery its not working.

Comment: @guest271314  If i type ap or apple means the correspondent values only should display other than should hide

Comment: any error in console, have you put jquery file on top of all script or not ?

Comment: @RajuSubramanian If input "ap" or "apple" show `tr` parent including both `td` elements, or `td` element containing text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If i type ap or apple means the correspondent values only should
>   display other than should hide

Note , not certain if expected result is to toggle `td` elements ? As `js` at Question appear to toggle `tr` elements ? To toggle `td` elements where text input matches `td` text, try adding `.find("td")` before call to `.show()` to substitute filtering `td` elements for parent `tr` elements

If input "app" only `td` containing text "Apple" should be displayed

```js
var $rows = $('#table tr');
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.find("td").show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
    });
```

```css
body {padding: 20px;}
input {margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 2px 3px; width: 209px;}
td {padding: 4px; border: 1px #CCC solid; width: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Search Event</title>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
    <link href="search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
   </head>
   <body>
     <center><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search"></center>
     <center><table id="table">
      <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Green</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Grapes</td>
       <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Orange</td>
       <td>Orange</td>
    </tr>
    </table></center>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

code is not working because your "search.js" file need jquery

in you code Jquery file missing with jquery it's working fine
it must be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
<link href="search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtmuhv68/)

Answer (score -1):

**Added jquery-1.9.1.js in html..**

```
<head>
<title>Search Event</title>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link href="search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
</head>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vq77u88y/)